# Add UIToolbar to UICollectionView header?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

In my storyboard I have added a UIToolBar to the Header of my CollectionView Like so:

[image]

I have created the header by selecting the section header box:

[image]

However, when I run this, the toolbar does not appear at all.

I get the a warning entitled "Unsupported Configurations: Title set but using a system identifier (these attributes are mutually exclusive; the Title will be ignored)"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a UIViewController and add the delegates for the collectionView then you will be able to resize the collectionView and place a UIToolBar in the view as well.

Like this:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController<UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource>
```

Swift:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, FirstProtocol, SecondProtocol {
}
```

Comment: How would I write this in swift?

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a tool bar inside a collection view header. Instead, try to lower the collection view and place the toolbar on top on the collection view.

Hope This Helps

Comment: I have this all inside of a UICollectionViewController. How do I lower the collectionView inside of this?

Comment: You will need to use a UIViewController and add the delegates for the collectionView then you will be able to resize the collectionView and place aUIToolBar in the view as well.